# find hypotenuse using adjacent and theta

Tags: trigonometry

It has been a couple of years since math class, but I'm trying to find the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle.

The adjacent length is $6$ cm and $\theta$ is $15$ degrees. How do I work this out?

So far, I've tried using $\cos() \cdot 6 =$ hypotenuse. However, every time I press equals it seems to give a new answer?

Comment: Please check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\cos$ is defined by $$\cos \theta = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$$

So we have $$\cos 15^\circ=\frac{6}{\text{hypotenuse}}\implies\text{hypotenuse}=\frac{6}{\cos 15^\circ} $$

$$\implies \text{hypotenuse} = \frac{6}{\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{4}}=6(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})$$

Answer (score 0):

You should divide, not multiply.

$$ hyp.. =\frac{6}{\cos 15^0}$$